# Mapping MongoDB Json Update statements to POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson, jackson2

When creating a MySQL mirror from MongoDB source, we are handling many different update statatements that are set as idempotent operations in the mongo oplog.

The issue is when we're dealing with $set statements in multiple formats, and we want to map these all to the same json/POJO object (using Jackson).

For example.

Original Document: 
`{"name":"test","about":{"address":{"line1":"101 Main St.","line2":"Apt 1"},"phone":"555-5555"}}`

Update Format1: `$set: {"about.address.line1" : "222 Main St"}`

Update Format2: `$set: {"about":{"address":{"line1" : "222 Main St","line2":"Apt 1"},"phone":"555-5555"}}`

Update Format3: `$set: {"about.address":{"line1" : "222 Main St","line2":"Apt 1"}}`

All three of these above formats should map to the same. I am able to handle Format1 by changing the ":" to "=" and using ObjectMapper fieldMapper = new ObjectMapper(new JavaPropsFactory());

I'm also able to handle converting Format2 using ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

My problem is when trying to convert Format3 - because it has both dot notation as well as a json object. Is there a straightforward way to convert dot notations into nested json object, so that the ObjectMapper can be used to map this jsonnode to POJO? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to apply object mapper again?

Comment: I can apply the object mapper for format1 and format2, but since format3 is a combination of dot and object notation it does not map correctly.

Comment: Why it doesn't map could you elaborate.

Comment: For example, in format3 above when using the ObjectMapper from string to java class, attempts to find the field "about.address" in the POJO, but that is not found (there is a nested class "about" that has an "address" field).

Comment: You can split the object name using dot separator and invoke setters on the fields.